# Swift - IBAction vs Delegate vs addTarget

Tags: ios, swift

Just got started on learning Swift with Xcode (after years of .NET development) and have been going through a few videos and noticed varying ways in which people interact with UI Controls (e.g. UITextField). 
The three ways I have seen are:

1. Have the ViewController implement the corresponding controls delegate protocol (e.g. UITextFieldDelegate), and then implement the corresponding function for the required event.
2. Create an IBAction from the interface builder.
3. Programmatically wire up a handler with controlName.addTarget(...)

Can someone please explain the pros and cons of each approach and whether one is considered better practice than the others (and in which case is applicable)?

Any insights are much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Wiring up" `IBAction` in the storyboard or xib is equivalent to adding a target programmatically and is really just a matter of preference.  If you're going to use storyboards or xibs, the common practice is to wire up the controls there just to make it easier to find.  Additionally, you will need to wire up `IBOutlet` to the controls that you want to be able to access in code.

The delegate methods are actually something quite different from the other two options that you mentioned. For example, a `UITextFiled` will have a few properties and actions that you can wire up directly, but there are several delegate methods that you'll need to implement in order to take advantage of much of the functionality, such as responding to each individual character typed by the user.

Here are some tutorials that illustrate [wiring up](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113388/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1) and [delegate methods](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

Delegates are great for sending and receiving data between two objects. It can be used to have classes explicitly conform to protocol's required functions. For example `UITableView`, its required that you at least let to TableView how many rows, sections and what cells to populate in those indexPaths.

1.
However with `UITextFieldDelegate` its just a nice way to document the events that happen.

2.
The IBAction is only available if you're doing things via interface builder. It links up actions that are within UIControl (`UITextField` parent class) so you can get user input/action events and link them in code. Using IBAction simplifies your code (because there's less code to write)

3.
controlName.addTarget(...) is the programatic way to handle the IBAction link. My recommendation is if you're going with storyboards/interface builder stick with IBAction. Its easier that if you delete an object from your Storyboard it automatically unlinks the target/action.

Setting targets is actually part of the UIControl class, and if your object type isn't UIView based (or something that inherits off UIControl) you obviously can't use addTarget(...) but your option is to use a custom delegate/protocol.

UIControl typically is used to tell objects when a view has been changed by the user. The events are listed in this [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlEvents).

The delegation/protocol design pattern is much more flexible. For example if you wanted to stop a user from typing symbols by implementing `textField(textField:,shouldChangeCharactersInRange:,replacementString:) -> Bool` where as the UIControl can really only tell you if the text field has been changed.